# Windows 7 not finding hard drives?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

So, I just got a new SSD and installed it on my laptop (and a larger HDD).

When I went to install Windows 7 on my SSD, it saw all 3 disks just fine.  Once I booted into Windows though, it only sees the disk it was installed on.

Not sure where to start with this one.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Windows 7 installer will show all drives and partitions, regardless of formatted state.

Once you're in Windows 7, only drives that have mountable filesystems will be displayed.  You'll need to use System Management to format the drive, either NTFS or FAT.

Be careful, when formatting, that you don't select the incorrect drive/partition and lose your data!  :)